# How do I enable Handwrite on the Google Search app for iOS?

Tags: ios, search, google, google-apps, handwriting

I figured how to enable the Google Handwrite feature from Safari (Browse to google.com/preferences. and enable handwrite), but cant seem to find a way to do the same in the Google Search App for iOS.

Anybody been able to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think that's just a feature of Google's mobile site. I don't know that there's a way to enable it in the Google Search App. Perhaps they will add this feature down the road. I'll edit my answer if I find it is possible.

Comment: No prob. I was wondering this same thing a few weeks ago lol. Their handwriting rec works well. I wish there was a (free) note-taking app that worked this well lol

Comment: oh yeah...its pretty slick. Im just really surprised the search app doesnt have it already. You'd think...right?